# Android combining two LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, layout, layoutparams

I am attempting to fix both the Width and the margins of a ProgressBar with layout params

The following correctly sets the layout_margin

```
int finalHeight = soundcloudImage.getHeight() / 8;
int finalWidth = soundcloudImage.getWidth() / 4;

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams progressParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)progressBar.getLayoutParams();

progressParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, finalHeight);

progressBar.setLayoutParams(progressParams);
```

And this successfully sets the Layout_Width

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(finalWidth*2, 20);

progressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

However I cannot seem to combine the statement to get them to work together

Here is the layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/soundcloudimage" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#EA4F17" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be great

**EDIT:** attempted the following

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams progressParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)progressBar.getLayoutParams();
progressParams.width=finalWidth*2;
progressParams.height= 20;
progressParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, finalHeight);

progressBar.setLayoutParams(progressParams);
```

and it results in this

[image]

**EDIT:** Also tried this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams progressParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(finalWidth*2, 20);
progressParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, finalHeight);    
progressBar.setLayoutParams(progressParams);
```

which creates this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams progressParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)progressBar.getLayoutParams();
progressParams.width=finalWidth*2;
progressParams.height= 20;
progressParams.setMargins(finalWidth, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight);

progressBar.setLayoutParams(progressParams);
```

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams progressParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(finalWidth*2, 20);
progressParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, finalHeight);    
progressBar.setLayoutParams(progressParams);
```

Comment: The width isnt set this way

Comment: With this code the progress bar margins are set, but the width acts as if its fill_parent

Comment: Your edit forces the width to work but the margin doesnt, will add image as edit

Comment: can you post your layout as well?

Comment: use the getLayoutParam one(first one) and in your layout remove  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"